# Greek citizen wants to immigrate to Ireland with her South African husband. What is required?

Tags: immigration, eu, eu-citizens, eu-spouses, ireland

I am a Greek EU citizen living in South Africa wanting to move to Ireland with my non-EU citizen husband who is South African. What do we need for access to live and work in Ireland?

Comment: Welcome to Expatriates. What research have you done already? If reviewing http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa doesn’t answer your question, please edit it to explain exactly what you want to know or need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Greek citizen needs nothing special, just registration in social services and revenue.

The spouse needs Stamp 4 EU Fam

http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/registration-eutreaty

This is easy. You have to go Burgh Quay Registration Office and supply the following docs

http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/EU+Treaty+Rights

Comment: Revenue is not necessarily required.  There are several ways to qualify for free movement rights. One of them is to be employed.  The others do not involve revenue.

Comment: Yes, non-worker can live without revenue registration, but it is needed at last for family tax credit. Also revenue registration can significantly help in opening a joint bank account.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant.  I thought you meant that one needs to register in social services and that one also needs to have revenue.  That one should register with the revenue authority makes much more sense.

Comment: The question was "What do we need for access to live and work in Ireland?" If anyone or both in a couple needs to work, then both needs to be registered in revenue to get family tax credit.

Comment: Right.  I thought you were saying that they needed to have revenue (i.e., to have income) as a condition of qualifying to live in Ireland.